# HttpClient not writing to stream while downloading

Tags: c#, http, stream, win-universal-app, dotnet-httpclient

Currently I am implementing a way to report Progress with the HttpClient, since we share code with a .NET4 WPF and a Windows Universal App we use the Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries from NuGet. The idea was to wrap the target file stream in a `CountingInputStream` and report progress there:

```
 public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);

        _bytesRead += count;
        _progress.Report(_bytesRead);

        if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
```

Then I send my request with: `HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = AsyncHelpers.RunSync(() => _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken));`

After that I open the file stream and then copy the content stream. The response has correct headers:
`Content-Length: 213334`
`Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8`
`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Bondi Beach.jpg"; filename*=UTF-8''Bondi%20Beach.jpg`

```
using(Stream fileStream = new CountingInputStream(storage.Open(downloadRequest.TargetPath, FileMode.Create), downloadRequest.Progress, cancellationToken )) {                                               
                await HttpHeaderResponseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
       }
```

The problem is that the `StreamContent` only starts writing to the file stream after the download has finished. When it started writing progress reporting just works fine.

I already tried different approaches like:

- `ReadAsStreamAsync` and then copy the response stream to file stream
- `ReadAsStreamAsync` manually read to buffer and then write to file stream
- `_httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(){MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 4096};`to restrict the `BufferSize`

Any ideas how I could force the `ContentStream` to write to the file stream while it is still downloading?

UPDATE:
Following Luaans advice I tried to override the `WriteAsync` and implemented a StreamContent Extensions method:

```
//CountingInputStream
public Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _bytesRead += count;
        _progress.Report(_bytesRead);

        if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        return _stream.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
    }
//static Extensions Class
public static async Task CopyToAs(this StreamContent source, Stream targetStream)
    {
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        using(Stream responseStream = await source.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
            while ((read = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer,0,buffer.Length))>0) {
                await targetStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
```

It still waits till the download is finish until it calls `ReadAsync` the first time. Any hints what I have done wrong?

Comment: You're using asynchronous API, of course it's not going to call the synchronous `Write` method. However, instead of `CopyToAsync`, you could write your own code that does the required `ReadAsync`s and `WriteAsync`s, and reports progress along the way. Of course, since you're running the code synchronously, there's no time for the UI to render the progress anyway - it needs the UI thread for that. Try using asynchronous I/O all the way instead :)

Comment: unfortunately i am forced to write this code sync. I tried what you suggested and did a implementation of `WriteAsync` see Update, but it still doesn't work, any hints are welcome

Comment: Yeah, that likely means the time spent on the request isn't actually the download itself, but rather processing on the server, setting the connection up etc. Try with a bigger file. Although, now that I'm looking closer, why are you using `StreamContent` at all? And where are you getting it from?

Comment: i did some further testing and found out it is because of the  PCL class library, will try to move my code to a Universal class library.

Comment: Ok i was wrong,  on Windows Phone  this way of progress reporting only works if the  file  already was once downloaded. On Windows Store Apps the same code works.  It doesn't matter if i use Async or not  it doesn't work on Phone

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If the file was already downloaded, it's available in the cache and thus ready to be used immediatelly, without making a network request in the first place. What progress is there to show?

Comment: The problem is that progress is only shown when cached,  because the  readasync waits until the complete file is downloaded until  it starts to read. it doesn't matter if I use  async I/O or not. And I only report progress when I can read from the incoming response stream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that `ReadAsStreamAsync` is, well, `async`, makes this rather suspicious. Why would you *asynchronously* wait to get the *stream*? You're supposed to read it asynchronously, but you should have the stream itself ready right away.

Reading the documentation makes this blatantly obvious:

> This operation will not block. The returned task object will complete after the whole response (including content) is read.

However, there's overloads you can use to have it return after the *headers* have been read. This still means you need to wait for the server to process the request, before starting to get progress, but for the download itself, you are in luck.

Sample code:

```
var response = 
 await 
 (
   new HttpClient()
   .GetAsync("http://www.microsoft.com/", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
 );

var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var buffer = new byte[2048];    

while (await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
{
  // Report progress and write to a different stream
}
```

**EDIT:**

It sounds like you should be using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instead of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`:

```
async Task DownloadWithProgress()
{
 var awaitable = httpClient.GetAsync(yourUrl)

 awaitable.Progress = (res, progress) =>
 {
   // Report progress
 }

 await awaitable;   
}
```

Comment: That is exactly how I implemented it. Have you run this code on Windows Phone?  It works on Windows Store Apps but on WP it waits after  `await stream.ReadAsync(buffer,0,buffer.Length)`  until the download is finished. It looks like a bug (feature) of  WP to me.

Comment: @Drako Weird. Well, `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` really is there explicitly for Web API, so it doesn't really violate anything about that - the processing of the request should always take much longer than the download, so why bother? If you're using it to download web sites (and images etc.), you should probably be using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instead - it ties in better with the download architecture in Windows Phone, and gives you a `Progress` event to handle showing the download progress in your application.

Comment: You are my hero :-) `var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`  and `await response.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(fileStream.AsOutputStream()).AsTask(token,progress);`  works. Thanks for staying with me